# Excel Hyperlink to accept "&"

Tags: c#-4.0

I am creating a Hyperlink in a Cell by using EPPLUS. But it is not accepting "&" symbol. could you please tell me how to allow "&" in hyperlink

Comment: Show us your code.  What error do you get?

Answer (score -1):

Use the encoded equivalent `&amp;`